# Can PouchDB be used in Node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, pouchdb

I've tried instantiating a PouchDB instance in node REPL.

In REPL:

```
var pouchdb = require("pouchdb");
var foo = new pouchdb("foo");
```

This always causes node to exit with the exception:

```
undefined:0
TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Can PouchDB be used in Node REPL?

Comment: I've had this problem as well and opened an issue https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a current pouchdb clone

```
~/src/pouchdb (master)$ npm run shell

> pouchdb@2.0.2-alpha shell /Users/daleharvey/src/pouchdb
> ./bin/repl.js

> var foo = new PouchDB('foo');
undefined
> foo.post({'a':'doc'});
[object Object]
>
==> leveldb foo bulkDocs
args: [{"docs":[{"a":"doc"}]},{},null]
result: [
  {
    "ok": true,
    "id": "3C8264BA-8966-4059-9FA2-401E464E54E8",
    "rev": "1-49e9d0c368f1114e0a0b67cdc808d6da"
  }
]
===
>
==> leveldb foo post
args: [{"a":"doc"}]
result: {
  "ok": true,
  "id": "3C8264BA-8966-4059-9FA2-401E464E54E8",
  "rev": "1-49e9d0c368f1114e0a0b67cdc808d6da"
}
===
>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is literally just the basic repl that doesn't work, starting a custom repl works fine for some unknown reason so running `node --eval "require('repl').start('> ');"` works